# Laravel manage different API responses

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

## Explanation

User scans barcode and system responses with a barcodable model (can be Article, Package or Inventory Shelf).

```
return new BarcodeResource($barcode);
```

Barcode resource resolves barcodable resource based on barcodable class. Each barcodable model return different JSON resouce.

```
// BarcodeResource.php

$modelResource = app()->makeWith(__NAMESPACE__ . '\\' . class_basename($this->barcodable) . 'Resource', [
    'resource' => $this->barcodable
]);

return [
    'code' => $this->code,
    'model_type' => class_basename($this->barcodable),
    'model_data' => $modelResource
];
```

In case of...

- ... Article, I'd like to print packages that contain those kind of articles
- ... Package, I'd like to print location (inventory shelf), included articles and child packages
- ... Inventory Shelf, I'd like to print all packages

## Problem

**I want to prevent infinity loops with recursive resources.**

```
Article
  >> Package
      >> Article (infinity loop begins because package resource 
                  returns articles in spesific package)

Package
  >> Article
      >> Package (loop...)
  >> Inventory Shelf
      >> Package (loop...)
  >> Child package


Inventory Shelf
  >> Package
      >> Article
      >> Inventory Shelf (loop...)
      >> Child package
```

Eager loading and unsetting relations should be one solution, but how I can unset those in the correct phase? Is this even possible with one resources or should I make multiple resources (recursive/normal)?

---

## Tries

#### Extra attribute containing relations

I tried this solution, but magically `$this->relations` attribute gets changed to integer 1 after couple recursions...

```
class PackageResource extends JsonResource
{
    private $relations;

    public function __construct($resource, array $relations = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($resource);
        $this->relations = $relations;
    }

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'articles' => $this->when(in_array('articles', $this->relations), ArticleResource::collection($this->articles, $this->relations)),
            'children' => PackageResource::collection($this->children, $this->relations),
        ];
    }
```

Comment: related to the tries: loses the relationships, because the relationship is expected through the constructor, but you pass it through the collection method.

Comment: You should overwrite the collection method as well.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for a similar situation was as follows:
In the Resource files, I allways return relationships based on a request property `with`. This is attached to the request as follows:
I need the `User` with `Orders` and `Profile`, but I also need the `Area` for an order, than the request is something like this:

```php
http://example.com/api/v1/user/234?with=user.orders,user.profile,orders.area
```

and in the Resource file something similar:

```php
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $return = [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'location' => $this->location,
            'active' => $this->isActive(),
            'level' => $this->level,
        ];

        if($request->has('with')){

            $relationships = [
                'orders'=>[OrderCollection::class, 'orders'],
                'area'=>[Area::class, 'area', 'area.admin'],
                'profile'=>[UserProfile::class, 'profile'],
            ];

            $with = explode(',', $request->with);

            foreach($relationships as $key => $relationship){
                if( in_array("user.".$key, $with) ){
                    $return[$key] = new $relationship[0]($this->{$relationship[1]});
                }
            }
        }

        $return['created'] = $this->created_at->toDateTimeString();

        return $return;
    }
```

An other solution is to add an extra property to the resource class:

```php
    protected $with = "";
    public function __construct(mixed $resource, $with="")
    {
        parent::__construct($resource);
    }
```

Than, when you call that resource, you can filter it in the previous way. I just tested and it worked for me.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I dont't want to give any extra parameters in URL because the request should be exactly same whatever the returned barcodeable model is. I tried to inject extra attribute to resource from controller, but I didn't get it to work yet.

Comment: You wasn’t able to insert extra attribute?

Comment: Yes, I was but when I pass it forward to another resource it changes to value integer 1 (before string containing relations). So the original attribute value is somehow gone.

Comment: For some reason it's not working when I try to pass param forward: `$return[$key] = new $relationship[0]($this->{$relationship[1]}, $with);` becuse the with attribute changes to integer value 1. I don't get why it does like that...

Comment: You should create resource controllers with the command `php artisan make:resource UserCollection` and use them with the `new Resourcecontroller(Model)` style. You loose the relationship, because you pass it to the collection static method and not to the ResourceController's constructor.